# Bleak discovering only the old hostname of bluetooth device instead of the updated one under macOS

Tags: python, macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

When discovering nearby Bluetooth devices using BleakScanner or bleak.discover only the outdated hostname of the Raspberry Pi is discovered. I reset the Pi and updated the hostname. A Bluetooth scanner app also picks up the updated hostname so the problem seems to be on the side of macOS. I also deleted the bluetooth.plist file and rebooted but was not successful. Somehow the old hostname is still cached in a way and the new one is not recognised. Is there a way to reset the Mac's Bluetooth further?

Bleak 0.21.1
macOS Ventura 13.6

What did not help so far:

- reboot Pi
- delete bluetooth.plist
- reboot Mac
- update Bleak
- update Python
- reset Pi and update hostname
- activate Bluetooth discovery on Pi

BleakScanner script running on Mac

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner


async def discover_devices():
    scanner = BleakScanner()

    devices = await scanner.discover()

    for device in devices:
        if device.name:
            print(f"Found device: {device.name}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(discover_devices())
```

Comment: Without code for context this is just a journal entry.

Comment: True! Head was full yesterday @tadman